# Solving differential equation with Fourier-series-inhomogenity

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-series, periodic-functions

Let $\lambda$ be a real number , $(c_k)$ a complex sequence with $\mid c_k \mid  \leq C(1+\mid k \mid)^{-2}$ for all k with a constant $C \geq 0 $. Find all periodic, two times differentiable functions $f:R -> R$ which fulfil the differential equation 
\begin{equation*}
f''-\lambda f'+f=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty c_ke^{ikx}. 
\end{equation*}
I already solved the homogenous equation with
\begin{equation*}
f(x)= c_1 e^{1/2 (\lambda-\sqrt{\lambda^2-4} )x}+c_2 e^{1/2(\lambda+\sqrt{\lambda^2-4})x} 
\end{equation*}
sadly thats as far as I come. Can someone help me out on this one?

Comment: Don't be sad. :-) Write $f(x)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \hat{f}(k)e^{ikx}$ instead. Substitute in the equation then solve for $\hat{f}(k)$. (Notation: $\hat{f}(k)=\int_0^{2\pi}f(x)e^{-ixk}\, dx$)